# Asymptotics of Fourier-like integral with the method of steepest descent

Tags: integration, asymptotics, complex-integration

I am interested in finding the asymptotic approximation of the following integral:

$$ I(x,y) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k_{2}A}{k_{2}A+B}\frac{e^{i(k_{1}x + k_{2}y)}}{k_{2}}dk_{1}$$

where

$$k_{2}=\sqrt{k^{2} - k_{1}^{2}}$$

and A and B are constants.

So far I defined my function

$$\phi(k_{1})=e^{i(k_{1}x + k_{2}y)}$$

from which I found the saddle points where $$\frac{d\phi(k_{1})}{dk_{1}}=0$$ which I found to be

$$k_{1,SP}=\pm\frac{kx}{r}$$

where $$r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

I am stucked in finding the steepest descent path because I don't know how to deal with the possible poles I have in the first expression of the integral. Can anyone give some hints on how to continue working on this derivation? I am interested in not only obtain the leading order term.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assume that $a = B/A > 0$, $x \in \mathbb R$, $y > 0$ and also that $\sqrt z$ is the principal branch and let $k_1 = k u$, then
$$I(x, y) = \int_{\mathbb R}
 \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 - u^2} + \frac a k} e^{k \phi(u)} du,$$
where $\phi(u) = i (x u + y \sqrt {1 - u^2})$. There is exactly one $u_0$ s.t. $\phi'(u_0) = 0$, and it can be shown that
$$I(x, y) = \frac {e^{i \alpha}} {\sqrt {1 - u_0^2}}
  \int_{\mathbb R} e^{k (\phi(u_0) + \phi''(u_0) u^2/2)} du +
 o(k^{-1/2})$$
for $k \to \infty$, where $e^{i \alpha}$ is the steepest descent direction at $u_0$.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim for your explanation!